# Strange behaviour retrieving values from a cursor query

Tags: android

Good day, Hope the tilte is not misleading. please take a look at the code snippet below and notice the commented parts:

```
//if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
if(cursor.moveToNext() == true){

         // do {
                Log.d(TAG, "Column Name in bindview is " + columnName);
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnName));

                Log.d(TAG, " name is " + name);


           // } while(cursor.moveToNext());
       //}
   }
```

now only when i use `cursor.moveToNext()` do i get a value for the string `"name"`.if i use the `do/while` statement as commented out in the above code or cursor.moveTofirst(), i get null value for the string. any idea why this is happening.

****Background***:* am calling/initalizing this `CursorAdapter` from `onLoadFinished()` of a `CursorLoader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to do this:

```
// Get the column's index
int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName); 
String name;

// You might want to check if the column exist with: 
// if(index == -1)
//    return;

// If you have move the Cursor's index, reset it:
// cursor.moveToFirst();

while(cursor.moveToNext()) { // == true is implied
    name = cursor.getString(index);
    Log.d(TAG, " name is " + name);
}
```

First find the column index outside the loop, the column index will not change unless you change the cursor. Then loop through all the valid results.

Comment: thanks for that!.. but this statement you made "Next we assume this is a new Cursor pointing to -1, otherwise add cursor.moveToFirst()" is slightly confusing, you didn't do that in your code. Thanks once again